# How to avoid returning reference to a local variable for user defined types of objects?

Tags: c++

I have a function which returns reference to a global variable under some conditions.
For the completeness of the code, I need to have another **not local** variable of the same type to return  correctly from the function in every situation. The global variable is of my own type.
Here is my code,

```
mytype_t a; // a is a global variable.

mytype_t &foo(bool b){

   if(b){
      return a;   //this is ok.  
   }

//Here, I need an object of mytype_t to get it back with return statement if b == false.
}
```

A solution for this situation would be to define a second *empty/null* variable. So, in cases where I shouldn't return the global variable `a`, I can return my second empty/null object. But, I have to make the second global object '`const`ant' to make sure that the empty variable is always empty. On the other hand, if I make the second variable constant, then it is not possible to return it from the function. Is there a more elegant solution to this situation?

The code below works fine if only the `mytype_null` object is not `const`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct mytype_t{
    mytype_t(int i=0, int j=0){x=i;y=j;}
    int x,y;
};

mytype_t a(8,5); // a is not empty. 

mytype_t mytype_null;  //mytype_null is an empty object.

mytype_t &foo(bool b);

int main()
{
    mytype_t c = foo(false);

    std::cout<<c.x<<"  "<<c.y<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}

mytype_t &foo(bool b){

   if(b) return a;

   return mytype_null;
}
```

Comment: `std::optional` ... and have a look at function-level static variables.

Comment: Various choices.   One is `std::optional`.   Another is to change the return type of your function to be a pointer instead of a reference, and return a null pointer when there is no object to return.  Both require the user to somehow check the return value before using it (e.g. using the optional data if present, pointer must be non-null before dereferencing).

Comment: "For the completeness of the code, I need to have another not local variable of the same type to return correctly from the function in every situation." - I sense an X/Y problem here. Your requirement does not make sense - you want to return a reference to something mutable in some situations, but a reference to something immutable in other situations. But how does the caller of the function know which was returned, so he can react appropriately (i.e. not modify)? And if the caller can know that, why can't he find out first and then not call the function at all?

Answer (score 0):

> But, I have to make the second global object 'constant' to make sure that the empty variable is always empty. On the other hand, if I make the second variable constant, then it is not possible to return it from the function.

It is possible to return a non-const reference to a const object by casting the const away. In such case attempting to modify the referred const object would result in undefined behaviour. That makes this approach unsafe, but it is sometimes reasonable as long as it is documented carefully.

Somewhat similar solution is used for example in case of `std::string` where `str[str.size()]` returns a non-const reference to the null-terminator, but modifying it is UB.

Another option is to return a pointer instead of a reference. Pointers have an explicit null value that represents pointing to nothing. Indirecting through a null pointer is UB, so this is similarly unsafe.

> Is there a more elegant solution to this situation?

Whether it is elegant is subjective, but a safe approach is to return from the function by throwing an exception.